# How can I pass the context to the Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a problem about the context like below.

This is the NetworkProvider.js provide the internet statue

```
import React from 'react';
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';

export const NetworkContext = React.createContext({
  isConnected: true
});

export class NetworkProvider extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    isConnected: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
  }

  handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => this.setState({
    isConnected
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <NetworkContext.Provider value={ this.state }>
        { this.props.children }
      </NetworkContext.Provider>
      );
  }
}
```

This is the ExampleComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

import { NetworkContext } from './network_provider';

export class ExampleComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  static contextType = NetworkContext;

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          You are now
          { this.context.isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline' }
        </Text>
      </View>
      );
  }
}
```

App.js

```
 static contextType = NetworkContext;
  render() {
    return (
      <NetworkProvider>
        <ExampleComponent />

        <View>
          <Text>
            You are now
            { this.context.isConnected ? 'online' : 'offline' }
          </Text>
        </View>
      </NetworkProvider>

      );
  }
}
```

ExampleComponent.js is correct if I change wifi on/off
but copy the code from the ExampleComponent.js  doesn't work it always online!
why amd how to modify it?
thank you!

Comment: Are you checking this change on Simulator or Emulator ? If so then things might not work as expected. Test the network change on actual device to see the result. Also you can use NetInfo.fetch() function to get the current network state.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are listening to connectionChange event this code will work only when the connection changes.

To listen to network connection once use this:

```
NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer!
I  do this in the function like below and I return `this.state.isConnected`  final and show it through console.But log show Undefine!

`function InternetStatus() {
  NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
    console.log("Connection type", state.type);
    console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
    return this.state.isConnected
  });

}`